# Can i add code inside a div content in html page?

Tags: html, css

can i add a code inside a content of div ?

for example

```
<div class="spmeStyle">CAN I ADD CODE HERE?</div>
```

code mean anything like style or something , is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put HTML inside of div. `<div>html here</div>`